# Why do I get different values when trying to retrieve BrickColor.Name of a part from different scripts on roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I writing a simple game in Roblox.

One script in the player changes the color of all grey blocks the player touches.
Other script in a part makes it blink. This part should stop blinking when it is touched and then it's color changes.

When I touch the block the rendered color and the color name in the player's script changes but not the color name in the part script. 
I added some prints to help me to figure out what is going on.
I know it is possible to solve it with an event. But why the different values?

This script is in the StarterCharacterScripts object:

```
print(":)")

local originalColor = BrickColor.new(0.639216, 0.635294, 0.647059)

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local human = player.Character.Humanoid

print("Player logged:  " .. human.DisplayName)

human.Touched:Connect(function(hit,limb)
    if hit.BrickColor.Name == originalColor.Name then
        hit.Color = player.TeamColor.Color
    end
end)

while true do
        print("From human: " .. workspace.Test.BrickColor.Name)
        wait(3)
end
```

This other script is in the object:

```
local greyPart=script.Parent
local myColor = greyPart.Color




print(greyPart.Name)
print(script.Parent.Name)

while myColor == script.Parent.Color do
    greyPart.Transparency = 1
    wait(1)
    greyPart.Transparency = 0
    wait(1)

    print("From part: " .. workspace.Test.BrickColor.Name)
end
```

The output I get before touch is something like this:

```
From human: Medium stone grey
From part: Medium stone grey (x2)
```

And after touch something like this:

```
  From human: Really red
  From part: Medium stone grey (x2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, making changes to the Workspace with LocalScripts only apply those changes to the Player that owns the LocalScript.

You can see this in action if you play the game from the Test tab of Studio, and run it with 3 players and the server.
I made a simple LocalScript in StarterCharacterScripts that changes the brick to a random color. This is how it looks on all the different clients and the server :

**Server :**

[image: Server side view of grey brick and 3 players standing around it.]

**Player 1 :**

[image: View from Player 1's perspective. The brick is red.]

**Player 2 :**

[image: View from Player 2's perspective. The brick is white]

**Player 3 :**

[image: View from Player 3's perspective. The brick is blue]

If you want a change to be replicated to all players, it must happen in a Script.

Answer (score 1):

> I know it is possible to solve it with an event. But why the different values?

Using a `RemoteEvent` is the solution to this problem, as you are trying to effect a server-side change from the client. In the Roblox client-server model, the server is authoritative and is only one that can make changes to objects in the game world. When a client makes a change in the way you are doing with your script, that change is visible from the local client's point of view; however, the change *does not* replicate to the other players. This explains the output from your scripts: on your screen, the block's `BrickColor` has changed, but from another player's perspective it would still be grey.

A `RemoteEvent`, as well as a `RemoteFunction`, can send signals from a client which are then received by the server; these signals can tell the server to make a change to the game world, which all clients will be able to see. In your case, your client-side script, which detects what grey parts a player touches, would send that information to the server via a `RemoteEvent` and tell it to change the part's `BrickColor`.

The Roblox reference page for the `RemoteEvent` class says the following:

> A `RemoteEvent` is designed to provide a one-way message between the server and clients, allowing `Scripts` to call code in `LocalScripts` and vice-versa. This message can be directed from one client to the server, from the server to a particular client, or from the server to all clients.

In your case, you would be directing a message from one client to the server, calling a function contained in a server-side `Script` from a `LocalScript`.

See the `RemoteEvent` reference page [here](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/RemoteEvent) for examples and more details.